# PHP file script showing and the method is not running?

Tags: php

I've looked online however I can't seem to get my head around this problem.Below is the screenshot of the code which is showing. I have Apache and MySQL running.
Any help would be amazing!

[image]

Below is my code for the form.

```
Name: <input type = "text" name = "Full Name">
MobileNumber: <input type = "interger" name = "Mobile Number">
Email: <input type = "text" name = "Email">
Address: <input type = "text" name = "Address">
PostCode: <input type = "text" name = "Post Code">
Interests: <input type = "text" name = "Interests">
<input type = "submit" value = "Enter">
</form>
```

Comment: In your screen shot, the page is being served up locally by your *client* computer, which I would expect is not running Apache, and therefore it is not processing the PHP code.

Comment: it is a php code u need to run it in a server like wamp server

Comment: To make this work you'll need to  load this file onto a web server with PHP installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is simple.

You can't run directly PHP as a file.
You have tu run it via your localhost (assuming you have PHP installed)

Locate where your "public_html" o "web" or "www" folder is.
And that is where you should put/move your PHP files.

After you move your file to the appropriate web folder, you can run it like this:

http://localhost/datanew.php

http://127.0.01/datanew.php

NOTE: when you call a PHP file outside a server environment, you are simply showing the content of your file. But if you call the file through a web server, then web server runs the PHP scripts and outputs the results of your PHP script.